# How to convert incorrectly encoded string to bytes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding

I've got utf-8 string in the form of 'РїРѕРј'... - in Python 3 string. How can I decode it (to get correct string)?

As I see from error messages I can only convert string from bytes array, but how to get it then? I tried

```
bytes(str, 'ascii', errors='ignore')
```

so it should not change existing byte values, but it removed all "incorrect" characters (I suppose because they have codes >= 128).

The example string contains Russian 'пом'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a string that has been encoded as *UTF-8*, then decoded as *cp1251*.

```
>>> s =  'пом'
>>> s.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1251')
'РїРѕРј'
```

You can get the original string by reversing the operation.

```
>>> e = 'РїРѕРј'
>>> e.encode('cp1251').decode('utf-8')
'пом'
```

If you want to encode the mojibake string as bytes, without losing information, use the *backslashreplace* error handler.

```
>>> e.encode('ascii', errors='backslashreplace')
b'\\u0420\\u0457\\u0420\\u0455\\u0420\\u0458'
```